# Join query with flattened result

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the following entities

[image]

AddressType is simply an enum field that define if the Email is Personal/Work/Other.

Is it possible to do a query that returns a flattened result like the one in the following sample?

```
CustomerID    Full Name       Personal Email         Work Email
-----------   --------------  -----------------      -----------------------
1             John Doe        johndoe@hotmail.com    john.doe@company.com
```

Comment: +1 for pseudo-hand-drawn schema; what tool is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two main choices:

1) Select it as typical (with two rows, one for each email), then use the [`pivot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) operator to flatten.

Example of `pivot` (I call it an example as I wrote it in notepad.  It may be slightly wrong, but it should point you the right way):

```
select
  CustomerID,
  FullName
  [1] as WorkEmail,
  [2] as HomeEmail
from
  (select 
    c.CustomerID, c.FullName, e.AddressText, e.AddressType
   from 
     Customer c
     join emails e on e.CustomerID = c.CustomerID) as Source
pivot (
  AddressText
  FOR AddressType in ([1], [2])
)
```

2) Join to the email table twice, once for each type of address.  Suggest outer joins so if one is missing you still get the other.

Comment: Can you give me a sample of the first case please? The second one is clear but it would be a little messy in my case as the values in the enum are seven... Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
select c.CustomerID, 
    c.FullName as [Full Name], 
    epersonal.AddressText as [Personal Email], 
    ework.AddressText as [Work Email]
from Customer c
left outer join Email epersonal on c.CustomerID = epersonal.CustomerID 
    and epersonal.AddressType = 'personal'
left outer join Email ework on c.CustomerID = ework.CustomerID 
    and epersonal.AddressType = 'work'
```